# How to default provider from appsettings.json using if else?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I have 2 providers as you can see below. If "IsDefaultProvider" section is "true" I want to get its values while injecting IConfiguration.

I write the below code I could not work

```
var providers = configuration.GetSection("X:Providers");
            foreach(var provider in providers.)
            {
                if (providers.GetSection("IsDefaultProvider").Value == "true")
                {
                    _defaultProvider = (XProviderType)Enum.Parse(typeof(XProviderType),  provider.Value.ToString());
                }
            }
```

**Appsettings.json**

```
"X": {
    "Providers": [
      {
        "IsDefaultProvider": false,
        "Name": "***",
        "BaseUrl": "https://*",
        "ApiKey": "*****",
        "SecretKey": "****"
      },
      {
        "IsDefaultProvider": true,
        "Name": "*****",
        "BaseUrl": "http://*"
      }
    ]
  }
```

Comment: What is not working? Are you getting an exception? If so, post the stack trace.

Comment: I am not getting exception. I cannot get the name of the provider which IsDefaultProvider value equal to true

Comment: Can you accept one of the answers below if you went with one of those options please?

Answer (score 1):

For mapping Configuration from `appsettings.json` to `Provider`, try follow steps below:

- Define model for `Provider`

  ```
  public class Provider
  {
      public bool IsDefaultProvider { get; set; }
      public string Name { get; set; }
      public string BaseUrl { get; set; }
      public string ApiKey { get; set; }
      public string SecretKey { get; set; }
  }

  public class X
  {
      public List<Provider> Providers { get; set; }
  }
  ```
- Get Default Provider

  ```
  var providers = Configuration.GetSection("X").Get<X>();
  foreach (var provider in providers.Providers)
  {
      if (provider.IsDefaultProvider == true)
      {
          //var _defaultProvider = (XProviderType)Enum.Parse(typeof(XProviderType), provider.Value.ToString());
      }
  }
  ```

Answer (score 1):

There are two problems in the code you've shown in your question:

1. `providers.` does not compile. I expect this might just be a bad copy-paste but I'm pointing it out just in case as it should be `providers.GetChildren()`.
2. When parsing a JSON boolean value, the string representation is e.g `True` rather than `true`, so you need to compare against this (or just do so case-insensitively).

Here's a working example:

```
var providers = configuration.GetSection("X:Providers");
foreach (var provider in providers.GetChildren())
{
    if (provider.GetSection("IsDefaultProvider").Value.ToLower() == "true")
    {
         _defaultProvider = ...
    }
}
```

I would also swap out the use of `GetSection("IsDefaultProvider")`, simply because `IsDefaultProvider` is not a section: it's a property. Here's an example of how that simplifies the code a little:

```
if (provider["IsDefaultProvider"].ToLower() == "true")
```

Having said all of that, [Tao Zhou's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53294201/2630078) is a much more type-safe way to handle this process if you have no objections to creating those additional classes, so I'd encourage you to consider using his approach instead.